# Space between div in postion: relative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm builiding a navigation panel which is over header. I used `postion: relative` and I subtracked few px (#navigation).

The height of the section header is reserved as if the navigation panel has not been moved. I would like that section to be closer to the header with no break.

How can I do it?

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#conteiner {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#conteiner>* {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#spacer-up {
  background-color: #8dc63f;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#frame-header {
  max-height: 400px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#spacer-down {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation {
  width: 450px;
  height: 130px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: -65px;
}

.button1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #00984a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #007639;
  transition: 0.2s;
}


/* Content */

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

footer {
  background-color: #007639;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <div id="conteiner">
    <header>
      <div id="spacer-up"></div>
      <div id="frame-header">
        <img src="/img/header-background.png" alt="" width="1138" height="369">
      </div>
      <div id="spacer-down"></div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <div class="button1">TEXT1</div>
        <div class="button1">TEXT2</div>
        <div class="button1">TEXT3</div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="content">
        SECTION 1
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>
 <body>
```

Comment: Without #navigation {top: -65px} the section is just below the header

Comment: Yes, that is what `position: relative` does. That's why it's rarely used for layout. I'm not quite sure I understand what exactly you are trying to do, but try a negative `margin-top` instead.